# Swift / Facebook like button / how to confirm that the user already set like

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm using the following code:

```
    let likeControl:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
    likeControl.objectID = "geckoclubmuc"
    likeControl.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
    likeControl.frame = CGRectMake(58, 407, 200, 40)
    likeControl.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    self.view.addSubview(likeControl)
```

The like button is displayed. After the user liked the page, it shows how many users like it. If the app restarts, the Like button is "reset".

How can I save that the user already did liked the page (and keep display the likes amount)?

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Like gating is not allowed.

Comment: so what would be the best practise? disable forever after liked?

Comment: Like gating is not allowed so doing something because the user liked the page is not allowed

Comment: well. ok. thank you for your effort

Comment: i have the same problem.. the button is reset everytime = is completely useless, i think is a bug from Facebook or something